# Unwanted multiple presses when using GPIO button press detection

Tags: gpio, switches

I use this to detect momentary button (connected to GPIO) press :

```python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO  
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  
GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)  

def my_callback(channel):  
    print channel

GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)  

raw_input()
```

Even with the *debouncing* thanks to `bouncetime=300`, I often get 2 messages instead of just 1 for a single button press.

**How to detect properly one button press ?**

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's not too late to answer your question; I encountered the same issue and wanted to post the solution I found! What I did was using the [buttons and switches introduction](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/projects/raspberrypi/tutorials/robot/buttons_and_switches/) on the official Raspberry site and their workaround.

It doesn't use `add_event_detect` but defines a function (called `BtnCheck`). What I use looks like this:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

# setup everything
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(12, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
count = 0
prev_inp = 1

# define a function that checks for buttons pressed. The heart of the answer...
def BtnCheck(PinNr):
    global prev_inp
    global count

    inp = GPIO.input(PinNr)
    if ((not prev_inp) and inp):
        count = count + 1
        print "Button pressed"
        print count
    rev_inp = inp
    time.sleep(0.05)

try:
    while True:
        BtnCheck(12)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: This isn't particularly helpful in that one is probably using the event detection functions to avoid this type of looping in the first place.

Answer (score -4):

I would suggest you use pygame libraries and detect a key press event. It works....

Comment: How would one do that? And what is the benefit of using pygame before other means of accomplishing this?